# Finding Which Program Runs Another

Tags: linux, bash, shutdown

I have an NAS running on a limited version of what appears to be Redhat Linux.  I followed directions to hack it so I could have shell access, which has been a big help.  I've also made a couple modifications, ones that others have done and, other than one issue, they all seem to work fine.

Somehow, every 22 days, the system shuts down.  I used a script running ps to find that shutdown is actually called, but I don't know what program calls shutdown.

If I rename /sbin/shutdown, then I could write a script to replace it.  But the most important piece of information I'd like is what program is calling shutdown.

If a program runs my script (the phony /sbin/shutdown), how can I find out what program called my script?  I want to be able to, from within the script, determine what program called the script in the first place.  If it makes it easier, I can always use a Perl script instead of a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, `ps -p $$ -o ppid=`. The output is the pid of the parent process (the calling process). Having the parent pid, you can read its command line from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` ([more on procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux)).

Answer (score 3):

Easiest is probably just to dump the full output of `ps afx` when your script gets called. That'll display a listing of all processes (including your script) in a tree format, showing not only what called your script, but what called *that*, and what else is running.