# Is a script called somewhere

Tags: linux, bash, cron

On one of my linux servers I have a script that performs some controls.
Is there a way of finding out where this script is called? This can be in 
another script, cobol program, crontab, ...
Opening every one of them will take a very long time.

Comment: You can gather some information with `ps -ef | grep your_script`.

Comment: Then I will only see the running processes. This scripts takes less than a minute to run. I think it only runs once a day or week.

Comment: Do have any guess about it? name, files involved, user executing it?

Comment: I think root is executing it. In the script are some alarms that didn't go off (disk full). Now there are big problems. The script was written before I started working here. I'm guessing somebody forgot to actually activate it, but I have to be sure.

Comment: Check crontab and things like that. You can also create a little cronjob for every minute writing the output of the `ps` in a log file. These traces may help.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925429/finding-which-program-runs-another and modify your script accordingly, maybe that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep for it:

- grep -lr yourscript /etc /opt/anotherlikleydir
- failing that, search the whole system : grep -lr yourscript /

Edit:

- failing that, search in binaries too: grep -lar yourscript /
- failing that, the script is either executed by a logged in user or a scripted remote login... if that's the case, try peachykeen's approach and edit the script... and why not dump a `ps axf` to a log too.

Comment: As a side note: This is pretty trivial unix stuff. You should probably invest in a good beginners book, or since it seems you're responsible for running the servers, find a training course.

Comment: He wants to find references to the script, not the actual script.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the script, put in a `ps` line to get the parent pid, `ps` again and grep for the parent pid to get the command, then log to file.

Come back in a week or so and you should have the command that is triggering your script. In case it's something nested, you may want to recurse or similar.

To do this without modifying the script, you'll need a watcher script/program that checks for access to the script file or calls `ps` every so often. However, if you have that kind of access, just modifying the script is probably easier.

**Edit:** Apparently the commands to get the parent pid and command for it, without repeatedly calling `ps`, look something like:

```
ps -p $$ -o ppid=
cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

([from jweyrich's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10925479/129032))